# Design patterns for finding a match

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Need assistance in structuring my code with design patterns.

So I have a single method in service class that looks like this. The constructor  loads a json file into a `List<Option>` of `Option` class instances. Finally when the service method is called it does some logic to find the `Option` match based on the parameter values and returns a new instance of 'Tool' class with the configured "options".

```
public Tool BestOptionFinderService.FindBestMatch(string value 1, int value2, int value3, .. bool value20, etc...) {..}
```

I'm not sure if I a "service" class is correct for this versus a "factory" or something else. I would appreciate your thoughts and suggestions on how you would design your code for this problem or similar.

Comment: Explain the logic of `FindBestMatch` in terms of the in parameters: valu1,value2,....

Comment: _So I have a single method in service class that looks like this_ - you forget to include a code of the method

Comment: It just loops through a `List<Option>` and finds the closest match to the combination of parameter values passed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, having single method with ~20 params is awful by itself, without even considering OOP patterns. Let's try to do better; more than that, let's try not to reinvent the wheel.

Important yet obvious observation: whatever matching logic one has, any object either matches or nor, and never both. Thus it makes sense to stick with Boolean algebra and signatures like `predicate: t -> bool` or `bool Predicate<T>(T obj)`. The other thing we know about predicates, is that one can easily reduce arbitrary two into a single one: there are different ways to do it, however you're obviously interested in the `and` or `&&` operator.

Thus, instead of having 20 parameters, you could have had twenty different **simple, clear, self-describing** predicates, later on "reduced" into a single instance. `Linq.Aggregate()` could help you out to not only beautify your code, but make it parallel (if necessary) as well. Then you could map your input to an sufficient (it's up to you to decide whether you do need more, or don't) number of flags, representing a "fitness" of a particular object you're examining.

Such an approach would indeed be better because:

1) You stick to well-known Boolean algebra,

1.A) which, actually, forms a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) under various operation, including `and`, which, in turn, makes it

1.B) easily distributable over any computation cluster

1.C) compact, expressive, self-explanatory.

2) Your code tells much more story: **simple** predicates are easy to read, maintain, unit-test and refactor, which is never the case for 20-params methods.

3) You clearly separate your primitives from a compositions - more complex structures, built up from somewhat known primitives. That's the way math goes and thus **the only** known **reliable, proven by thousands of years** way to tackle down the complexity and not get enslaved by it at some point.

4) There are more advantages, but I tired to type ;)